# Foundation 6 Orbit not Working in Django Template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a Foundation 6 Orbit with the slides comprising of a separate/ dynamic Django template inclusion as such:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space Pictures" data-orbit>
                <ul class="orbit-container">
                    <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span> &#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
                    <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span> &#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
                    {% for p in projects %}
                        <li class="orbit-slide">
                            {% include "project/project_landing_stub.html" %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

project_landing_stub.html:

```
<div class="callout small-12 columns" style="margin-top:30px;">
<a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}" style="color:black;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="small-12 columns" style="border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;">
            <p>{{ p.offer_title|truncatechars:100 }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{% if p.project.photo %}{{ p.project.photo.url }}{% endif %}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{ p.project.city }}, {{ p.project.country }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;">
        {% if p.offer_type == 'CO' %}

            <div class="small-4 columns padding-10">
                {% if p.annual_return %}
                <b>{{ p.annual_return }}%</b><br/>
                {% else %}
                <b>-</b><br/>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="small-gray">total yield</span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 columns padding-10">
                <b>{{ p.time_horizon }} </b><br/>
                <span class="small-gray">tenure (mth)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 columns padding-10">
                <p style="font-size: 12px;">
                    {% if p.loan %}
                        <b>{{ p.loan.get_payment_freq_display }}</b>
                    {% else %}
                        <b>End of Tenure</b>
                    {% endif %}
                    <br/>
                    <span class="small-gray">payout freq</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="small-6 columns padding-10">
                <b>{{ p.currency }} {{ p.min_investment }} </b><br/>
                <span class="small-gray">min. investment</span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns padding-10">
                {% if p.annual_return %}
                <b>{{ p.annual_return }}%</b><br/>
                {% else %}
                <b>-</b><br/>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="small-gray">projected return</span>
            </div>

        {% endif %}
    </div>

</a>
</div>
```

But it does not show, due to the orbit-container being rendered with 0px height property. Downloaded the Complete Foundation on 18th of July 2016, and using it here. The Orbit sample works fine if pasted in the same page, so I figured this has something to do with the dynamic generation of the orbit-slides using Django loop. Any idea?

Comment: Show `project/project_landing_stub.html` template, please.

Comment: Added project_landing_stub.html